Shopify: Getting "Payment Gateway is Invalid" Error in checkout complete API
We have a Shopify store and its website is already live. Customers can make the orders there and do the payment successfully. Now We are building a mobile app and using Shopify backend APIs to show the products and other flows.
While implementing the checkout, we are calling checkout storefront graphql APIs. Once we get the successful payment callback from RazorPay, we are calling checkoutCompleteWithTokenizedPaymentV3 shopify API but getting below error -
"Payment Gateway is Invalid"
When checkout complete API gets success, shopify will return an order object with order id. But due to this issue, the payment is being done at RazorPay but on calling checkout complete API, the order is not created in Shopify.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
